# Matlab uicontrol listbox return on close rather than immediately

Tags: matlab, callback, listbox, delay, uicontrol

I created a listbox using the lbox2 example in matlab, and as soon as it runs it returns the value. However i want the user to click on a value, and have the listbox return that value. It should also be noted i'm using an outdated version of matlab, 2007b.

For example,

```
    [handle,value] = myListbox;
    uiwait(handle);
```

However value returns immediately and is blank, since the user hasn't had a change to select anything yet. Since the code waits until the dialog is closed, which is desired, but when the window is closed its data is lost... i think.

Any idea how to get the return value after the user triggers the callback?

Full code:

```
function varargout = ListBox(varargin)
% LBOX2 Application M-file for lbox2.fig
%   LBOX2, by itself, creates a new LBOX2 or raises the existing
%   singleton*.
%
%   H = LBOX2 returns the handle to a new LBOX2 or the handle to
%   the existing singleton*.
%
%   LBOX2('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%   function named CALLBACK in LBOX2.M with the given input arguments.
%
%   LBOX2('Property','Value',...) creates a new LBOX2 or raises the
%   existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%   applied to the GUI before lbox2_OpeningFunction gets called.  An
%   unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%   stop.  All inputs are passed to lbox2_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%   *See GUI Options - GUI allows only one instance to run (singleton).
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Copyright 2000-2006 The MathWorks, Inc.

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help lbox2

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 30-Oct-2015 13:36:34

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',          mfilename, ...
               'gui_Singleton',     gui_Singleton, ...
               'gui_OpeningFcn',    @lbox2_OpeningFcn, ...
               'gui_OutputFcn',     @lbox2_OutputFcn, ...
               'gui_LayoutFcn',     [], ...
               'gui_Callback',      []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
   gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before lbox2 is made visible.
function lbox2_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to lbox2 (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for lbox2
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

if nargin == 3,
    initial_dir = pwd;
elseif nargin > 4
    if strcmpi(varargin{1},'dir')
        if exist(varargin{2},'dir')
            initial_dir = varargin{2};
        else
            errordlg('Input argument must be a valid directory','Input Argument Error!')
            return
        end
    else
        errordlg('Unrecognized input argument','Input Argument Error!');
        return;
    end
end
% Populate the listbox
load_listbox(initial_dir,handles)
% Return figure handle as first output argument

% UIWAIT makes lbox2 wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = lbox2_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;
varargout{2} = handles.systemType;

% ------------------------------------------------------------
% Callback for list box - open .fig with guide, otherwise use open
% ------------------------------------------------------------
function listbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to listbox1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = get(hObject,'String') returns listbox1 contents as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from listbox1

get(handles.systemType);
get(handles.listbox1,'Value');
get(handles.figure1,'SelectionType');


if strcmp(get(handles.figure1,'SelectionType'),'open')
    index_selected = get(handles.listbox1,'Value');
    type_list = get(handles.listbox1,'String');
    setappdata(hObject, 'systemType', type_list{index_selected}); 

    close(handles.figure1);
end
% ------------------------------------------------------------
% Read the current directory and sort the names
% ------------------------------------------------------------
function load_listbox(dir_path,handles)

%dir_struct = dir(dir_path);
%[sorted_names,sorted_index] = sortrows({dir_struct.name}');
handles.file_names = {'option1', 'option 2', 'option 3','option 4'};
handles.systemType = '';
%handles.sorted_index = sorted_index;
guidata(handles.figure1,handles)
set(handles.listbox1,'String',handles.file_names,...
    'Value',1)


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function listbox1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to listbox1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: listbox controls usually have a white background, change
%       'usewhitebg' to 0 to use default.  See ISPC and COMPUTER.
usewhitebg = 1;
if usewhitebg
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
else
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'));
end


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function figure1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Add the current directory to the path, as the pwd might change thru' the
% gui. Remove the directory from the path when gui is closed 
% (See figure1_DeleteFcn)
setappdata(hObject, 'StartPath', pwd);
addpath(pwd);


% --- Executes during object deletion, before destroying properties.
function figure1_DeleteFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Remove the directory added to the path in the figure1_CreateFcn.
if isappdata(hObject, 'StartPath')
    rmpath(getappdata(hObject, 'StartPath'));
end
```

So after the item is double clicked on, the function should return 'option1' 'option 2' 'option 3' or 'option 4'
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by *lbox2 example* - could you provide more complete code?

Comment: Do you refer to [this example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/interactive-list-box-in-a-guide-gui.html#f6-17499)? If so, did you modify the original code (e. g. the original code, just returns one output). Could you post your whole code?

Comment: Yes, that example. also, added the full code for the list box. @il_raffa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having the callback close the box, i changed close(h) in the callback to uiresume(h), then used the following code to use the listbox and get the value from it.

```
%prompt listbox
h = ListBox();
uiwait(h);

%get response from list box
appdata = getappdata(h);
type = appdata.systemType; %this was the information i was trying to get

%close the window
close(h);
```